# multiple elements with type effect JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two elements with typing effect using javascript, every element has its own function to make the typing effect, the problem is the two texts get displayed incompletely, but when I comment out one of the two functions all of the characters get displayed. And here is my index.js:

```js
const h1Txt = 'this is h1';
const headerP = 'this is paragraph!';
let i = 0;

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('typing');

  executeAsynchronously([typeWriter, typeWriter2], 100);

});

function executeAsynchronously(functions, timeout) {
  for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(functions[i], timeout);
  }
}
// The typewriter method for h1
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < h1Txt.length) {
    document.getElementById('h1-text').innerHTML += h1Txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, 100);

  }
}



// The typewriter method for p
function typeWriter2() {
  if (i < headerP.length) {
    document.getElementById('p-text').innerHTML += headerP.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter2, 100);
  }

}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-floating" id="h1-text"></h1>
<p id="p-text"></p>
```

Comment: Both functions use the same global `i` variable, how would you expect that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same `i` global variable for both functions causes `i` takes unexpected values. You can create one function to control the typing, and `i` will be in the `type` function's scope:

```js
const h1Txt = "this is h1";
const headerP = "this is paragraph!";

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  executeAsynchronously([
    [h1Txt, "h1-text", 100],
    [headerP, "p-text", 100]
  ]);
});

function executeAsynchronously(texts) {
  texts.forEach(args => type(...args));
}

function type(text, id, delay) {
  const node = document.getElementById(id);
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      node.textContent += text.charAt(i);
    }, i * delay);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-floating" id="h1-text"></h1>
<p id="p-text"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue in your code is that, you are referring to the same variable `i` which is declared at the global level in both of your `typeWriter` functions.

By the time one of the `typeWriter` function gets executed, `i` value will be incremented and since both the `typeWriter` functions are referring to the same one of the character is not getting displayed in the output.

For eg.,

- `typeWriter1` gets executed first at the end of the function execution `i` will be `1`. And in the output it'll print `t` in the `h1Txt` text.
- Now consider `typeWriter2` gets its turn and getting executed, now this function is also referring to same `i` whose value is `1`. So, it'll not print `t` in `headerP` text.

So, the output is not getting displayed as expected.

Below is one of the ways you can fix this issue i.e., by using two different variables which will be referred in `typeWriter` functions.

```js
const h1Txt = 'this is h1';
const headerP = 'this is paragraph!';
let i = 0;
let j = 0;

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('typing');

  executeAsynchronously([typeWriter, typeWriter2], 100);

});

function executeAsynchronously(functions, timeout) {
  for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(functions[i], timeout);
  }
}
// The typewriter method for h1
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < h1Txt.length) {
    document.getElementById('h1-text').innerHTML += h1Txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, 100);

  }
}

// The typewriter method for p
function typeWriter2() {
  if (j < headerP.length) {
    document.getElementById('p-text').innerHTML += headerP.charAt(j);
    j++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter2, 100);
  }

}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-floating" id="h1-text"></h1>
<p id="p-text"></p>
```

Comment: thx man for the comprehensive answer, and the simplicity

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same 'i' for both, the characters are gets missed out because of that.
I've simplified the code a bit, here'a  working sample in codepen:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('typing');

  executeAsynchronously([
    typeText('h1-text', 'this is h1'),
    typeText('p-text', 'this is paragraph!'),
  ], 100);
});

function executeAsynchronously(functions, timeout) {
  for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(functions[i], timeout);
  }
}

function typeText(elementId, text) {
  let idx = 0;
  const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  let interval;
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    element.innerHTML += text.charAt(idx);
    idx++;
    if (idx == text.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-floating" id="h1-text"></h1>
<p id="p-text"></p>
```